# WriteProcessMemory in debugged process

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi

I try to write simple debugger. For simplicity, assume the debugger runs under Windows XP.

At first I create new process as follows:

```
CreateProcess(processName,
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        false, 
        DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        &startInfo, 
        &openedProcessInfo);
```

And when I try to read or write something in memory of debugging process there are some problems. For example:

```
    DWORD oldProtect;
    if(!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, breakpointAddr, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect)) {
        printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    SIZE_T bytesRead = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;        
    BYTE instruction;

    BOOL isOk = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, breakpointAddr, &instruction, 1, &bytesRead);
    BYTE originalByte = instruction;

    instruction = 0xCC;
    if(isOk && bytesRead == 1) {
        isOk = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, breakpointAddr, &instruction, 1, &bytesWritten);
        if(isOk) {
            isOk = FlushInstructionCache(hProcess, breakpointAddr, 1);
        }
    }
    if(!isOk) {
        printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
```

It works, but not everywhere. It works when the address to which I want to write(read) something, is located within executable module (.exe).

But when I try to write(read) something within DLL library (for example, read at address of function VirtualAlloc) **VirtualProtectEx returns false and GetLastError = 487** (Attempt to access invalid address) and **ReadProcessMemory also returns false and GetLastError = 299** (Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.)

Debug privileges are enabled but it has no effect.

Comment: Surely it is because you are using the wrong address.  It is entirely unclear from your snippet how you made sure you got the right one.  At least VirtualQueryEx() is required to find the proper base address.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, if you're running as administrator than the most likely cause of the problem is that breakpointAddr is an invalid address.  VirtualProtectEx giving you the "Attempt to access invalid address" error supports this conclusion.